# Addition numbers java and stops by entering 0

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, addition

I want to make an addition and if the user enters the digit 0 he multiplies all numbers together and the program stops. I've already been searching and keep trying, but I still can't figure it out.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class counting {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int number = 0, stop = 0;

        Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
        while(true) {
            System.out.print("Enter a number (stop with 0): ");
            number += kb.nextInt();

            if (number == stop) {
                System.out.println("Outcome of the numbers " + number);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare the input with the `stop`, not the total `number`:

```
int number = 0, stop = 0;

Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
while(true) {
     System.out.print("Enter a number (stop with 0): ");
     int input = kb.nextInt();
     number += input;
     if (input == stop) {
          System.out.println("Outcome of the numbers " + number);
          return;
     }
}
```

Sample input/output:

```
Enter a number (stop with 0): 1
Enter a number (stop with 0): 2
Enter a number (stop with 0): 3
Enter a number (stop with 0): 0
Outcome of the numbers 6
```